# Unresolved external symbol referenced in function _main when using OpenCV CascadeClassifier

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been trying to execute the below code but couldn't compile it.I searched for error by masking some lines as comments.Finally I reached `CascadeClassifier face_cascade;`by removing all the other lines from `face_cascade.load` to `rectangle(image,faces[i],Scalar(0,125,165),2,8,0);` But I couldn't understand what the error is!Did I declare CascadeClassiier in a wrong way?

Thank you in advance.

```c++
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image=imread("taylor_swift.jpg");  
    imshow( "input", image );
    cvtColor(image,image,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist( image,image );

    CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
    face_cascade.load( "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" );

    // Detect faces
    vector<Rect> faces;
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image,faces,1.5,3,0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE);

    for(size_t i=0;i<faces.size();i++ )
    {

        rectangle(image,faces[i],Scalar(0,125,165),2,8,0);
    }

    imshow( "Detected Face", image );

    waitKey();                   
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall cv::CascadeClassifier::~CascadeClassifier(void)" (??1CascadeClassifier@cv@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\vamsidhar muthireddy\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OPEN_CV_TEST\OPEN_CV_TEST\main.obj

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::CascadeClassifier::CascadeClassifier(void)" (??0CascadeClassifier@cv@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main    C:\Users\vamsidhar muthireddy\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OPEN_CV_TEST\OPEN_CV_TEST\main.obj

Error   3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   C:\Users\vamsidhar muthireddy\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OPEN_CV_TEST\Debug\OPEN_CV_TEST.exe 1
```

Comment: What error does it give during compilation?

Comment: I just included the error list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be seeing compiler errors like this:

```
/tmp/cckqEgtd.o: In function `main':
face.cpp:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x101): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `cv::equalizeHist(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x194): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::CascadeClassifier()'
face.cpp:(.text+0x1d7): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::load(std::string const&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x275): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, double, int, int, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Size_<int>)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x32a): undefined reference to `cv::rectangle(cv::Mat&, cv::Rect_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x36c): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x3af): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x3d7): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
face.cpp:(.text+0x3fa): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::~CascadeClassifier()'
face.cpp:(.text+0x4f3): undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::~CascadeClassifier()'
/tmp/cckqEgtd.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
face.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/cckqEgtd.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
face.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These kind of *undefined reference* errors occur when you do not link the executable against the required libraries.

If you are on a linux machine then you can use this to compile your code.

```
g++ face.cpp `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

**EDIT:**

Have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html . This link from the OpenCV documentation explains how to configure Visual Studio with OpenCV

Here is a property sheet you can use with minor modifications as per your setup to configure visual studio https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenNI2-Book/openni2book/master/props/OpenCV.props

You may need to change some paths according to your installation directory. Also you will have to change the library names according to the opencv version you have. For example if you have OpenCV 2.4.10 then you will replace `opencv_core246.lib` with `opencv_core2410.lib` and so on.

Comment: currently,I am working on windows.I thought the same about errors

Comment: Got it...!!!! It was a problem with libraries.I included the correct one and code is running fine.Thanks for pointing the mistake @Lakshay Garg